# Replace markdown tag around string with html tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, markdown

I'm trying to grab the content between two sets of double underscores, and replace it between two underline html tags, but my regex is not quite right.

```
const str = "__test__"
str.replace(/__(\wd+)__/g, "<u>$1<\/u>")

console.log(str)
```

Expected output: `<u>test</u>`

Comment: I think you meant `__(\w+)__` and `<u>$1</u>`

Comment: Or `/__([^\W_]+(?:_[^\W_]+)*)__/g`

Comment: @Thefourthbird woops, I forgot the end tag in the example, which is meant to be escaped (I think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(str.replace(/__(\w+)__/g, "<u>$1<\/u>"))
```

Comment: this works by itself, so my issue must be elsewhere. Thanks!